# Create "pages" of steps with Material UI/React Stepper (like Table Pagination)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, material-ui, uistepper

Using Material UI with React, I am attempting to create "pages" of steps for every 4 steps in a process.

The below attempt resulted in all 10 steps still showing in one view, while the pagination calculated the correct number of pages for every 4 steps.

```
return (
    <Grid>
      <Stepper>
        {statusArr.map((label) => {
          return (
            <Step key={label}>
              <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>        
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>
      <TablePagination
        component="div"
        count={statusArr.length}
        rowsPerPage={[4]}
        page={page}
        backIconButtonProps={{
          'aria-label': 'previous page',
        }}
        nextIconButtonProps={{
          'aria-label': 'next page',
        }}
        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
```

Ideally I would have every page of steps represented by Stepper "dots" shown [here](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#dots), rather than the table pagination look/functionality.

Please let me know if additional code is required for context, and thank you for your ideas/advice.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do a little math to get the right number of pages

```
...
const stepsPerPage = 4;
const pageCount = Math.ceil(statusArray.length / stepsPerPage);

return (
  <Grid>
    <Stepper>
      {Array(pageCount).fill().map(page => (
        <Step>
...
```